# Forcing image to resize to fit div

Tags: html, css

I'm having some trouble with the CSS for my page which displays social media style posts including images. When displaying the images they are placed inside of a div tag which is styled to try and reduce the size of the images and display the images horziontally next to eachother.

However, I am having the issue that the images still try to stack on top of each other and I can not get them to resize how I would like, especially on mobile. Currently based on some other thread here this is what I've got

```
.postImg{
    display: inline-block;
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
    object-fit: scale-down;
}

.postImgDiv{
    height: 100px;
}
```

[image: Example showing issue]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your image taking 100% of the row width. Change it to: `width: auto`.

Look at this (your case):

```css
.postImg{
    display: inline-block;
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
    object-fit: scale-down;
    border: 1px solid;
}

.postImgDiv{
    height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="postImgDiv">
  <div class="postImg">A</div>
  <div class="postImg">B</div>
<div>
```

After fix:

```css
.postImg{
    display: inline-block;
    height:100%;
    width:auto;
    object-fit: scale-down;
    border: 1px solid;
}

.postImgDiv{
    height: 100px;
    text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="postImgDiv">
  <div class="postImg">A</div>
  <div class="postImg">B</div>
<div>
```

Comment: Thanks, this worked for me on desktop, but the images were still huge on mobile, so I attempted to use a relative unit for the height of the div which for some reason did not have any effect on mobile still.

Comment: Yeah vw was the one I tried. For now mobile functionality doesnt matter too much though so I suppose I'll leave it as it is